# how to put form on windows taskbar in C#?

Tags: c#, taskbar, wmp

In C# I need to make something like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oc1P.png]

Any idea how to do that + autohide it with taskbar?
It should work like older versions of WMP.

Comment: Do want to hide it from the taskbar and display a notification icon? Or do you want to put your taskbar-icon to the right, next to the notification area?

Comment: do you mean `DeskBand` objects? have a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a Desk Band, which is a COM object implementing the interfaces [IDeskBand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),[IObjectWithSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IPersistStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and some others depending on the behavior you want (such as [IInputObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want user input). [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#desk_bands) is a good starting point on the msdn and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and)'s a CodeProject article about it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889290/how-do-i-place-my-custom-toolbar-deskband-on-taskbar-in-windows-7-win-wpf) on StackOverflow might also be worth looking at.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on CodeProject but the code dates back to 2002:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and

You might consider using the Windows 7/8 preview function when you hover over your taskbar icon however:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Look in Samples\Shell\ThumbnailToolbarDemo for a sample demonstrating the ThumbnailToolbar as seen in newer Windows Media Player.