# Adding WPF application in tray bar pogramatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

Is there a way to add a WPF application (with context menu) in the desktop's tray bar as we can add desktop and other links programatically.

[image]

Here is how I want the application to appear.

[image]

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon or https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/aacbc77c-4ef6-456f-80b7-1f157c2909f7/

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti it's a notification icon that is referred in the above solutions. What I'm looking for is something like that second image I have added in the questions above.

Comment: Do you need to customize tray area context menu or to add a [custom toolbar (deskband)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13889290/1207195)?

Comment: I have a WPF app with context menu in the notification icon. Instead of making it appear as notification icon, I want to show it as the Desktop is shown in the second figure  which was possible as per the first figure

Comment: Ok, see link in edited comment.