# Taskbar extension (like contacts)

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, taskbar

In Windows 10, you can activate different buttons (e.g. task view button, windows ink workspace button, contacts button) by opening the context menu of the taskbar.

This is something different than the classic tray icons, and similar to deskbands (which has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shobjidl/nn-shobjidl-ideskband2)?).

An example of the contacts button:

[image: Contacts button example]

How can one achieve this? Is there a API for this? Are there documents available?

Comment: I wouldn't take that "deprecated" too literally. The very page they link to says "In Windows 7, deskbands can still be implemented and thumbnail toolbars are not intended to replace them all. Not all applications will lend themselves to a thumbnail toolbar, and another solution such as a deskband or a task in a destination list might be the right answer for your application; you must decide which solution works best for your application as part of your development cycle."

Answer (score 3):

I think that you might be interested in **Shell Extensions**/ **Taskbar Extensions - Deskbands**, please refer to following web-sides for more informations:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/taskbar-extensions#deskbands
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468984(v=vs.85).aspx
- [How to write a shell extension in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811621/how-to-write-a-shell-extension-in-c)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx

Perhaps the **Taskbar API** of Windows should be helpful in your case. Please note that the explorer.exe would be responsible for loading your extension, so that writing it in `C#` might have some limitations due to different `CLR` runtimes loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It's commonly called a tray icon or [NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx).

The official class is still in Windows Forms, if you want to be more modern have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674761/can-i-use-notifyicon-in-wpf) on what your options are in WPF.

Comment: That's not really what I want, or at least it looks very different. Should I give more information about it? Is something missing in my question?

Comment: To me it looks like a notify icon that opens a form when you click it. How it's styled and how it looks is up to the programmer I guess.

Comment: When you look closely at the image, you see, that it is not inside of the notifyicon box, but to the left of it. Also you can (de-)activate it via the context menu of the taskbar itself and not a standalone program.

Comment: @hellow That's called a DeskBand. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889290/how-do-i-place-my-custom-toolbar-deskband-on-taskbar-in-windows-7-win-wpf). That's C++ territory for multiple reasons though.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shobjidl/nn-shobjidl-ideskband2: "Important  You should use thumbnail toolbars in new development in place of desk bands, which are not supported as of Windows 7." So it is still not the right thing?

Comment: I updated my question for more clarification. I hope this helps.

Comment: @nvoigt Deskbands can be created in other languages fine (eg. C#), apparently: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and